# Utility that combines a directory of image files into a movie (AVI or WMV)

Tags: video

I'm looking for a utility that can combine a directory full of hundeds or thousands of images into a movie. I want it to be as automatic a possible - I don't want to have to import the files into a video editing program, etc.

I'd like a free program if possible, and open source is a plus.

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 6):

I had a recommendation for [MEncoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/menc-feat-enc-images.html):

```
mencoder mf://*.jpg -mf -o output.avi
```

Comment: Is there anything that mencoder *can't* do ? :)

Answer (score 1):

[VDubMod](http://virtualdubmod.sourceforge.net/) can do this, [Check this tutorial](http://www.how-to-make-your-own-animation.com/quickanimation3.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Slideshow Maker](http://shareme.com/details/dvd-photo-slideshow-maker-v2-0.html) will do what you are looking to do.  It will take your JPGs and turn them into a MPG movie.